# OTA - myApp couldn't be installed at this time - Could not verify executable

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

After almost no problems for 6 months, I suddenly have a major problem when trying to distribute an app for inhouse testing over OTA: while installing the app (after download) I get the below error message -> screenshot. All of my testers also see the same message, so it's not bound to a single device.

The console on the device shows the following message:

```
preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.uNQth4/foo_extracted/Payload/myApp.app
```

The strange thing is: I can install the app over USB with Xcode. Also the validation for the AppStore upload is fine.

I already tried a lot:

- new Distibution Profiles
- checked if the UDIDs are inside the profiles
- checked for double profiles in the keychain
- did Xcode Voodoo (clean build, erasing derived data)
- tried to fix it with entitlements ('get-task-allow' = false)

Any idea to solve this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

[image: unable to donwload application]

Comment: Can you install your finished ipa by dropping it onto iTunes (not Xcode) while you're tethered and then sync?

Comment: Thanks Owen. No, that doesn't work either. In addition to the other "preflight_application"-error, I now also get:              could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/de.myapp-461650BC-AFF9-4D46-9F57-F21D9BBFE4ED'

Comment: Sounds like you've got a bad build.  I've gotten these at times, and for some reason the build just didn't go correctly.  If iTunes chokes on it, then something is bad in the build process.

Comment: [offtopic] You whiped out the app name, but it's still visible behind the alertview ;)

Comment: @basvk Not *all* of it :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further investigation the problem - once again - was caused by an invalid combination of Developer Provisioning Profile and Ad Hoc Distribution Profile. The problem was, that even the usual fixes didn't work (exchanging certificates etc.). Xcode always showed valid profiles.

I have read a lots of post that recommend a complete reinstallation of MacOS with the goal to have a clean installation of the KeyChain. I didn't want to kill my customized MacOS, so I created a virtual machine of Mac OS 10.7.3 + Xcode using VMWare. Then it was like 20 minutes to set everything up and the OTA worked! I think, it's a good idea to have a clean virtual OS handy for this case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the IPA file had a bundle-version number and the plist file had a different bundle-version number.

Changed the plist file to have the same number as the IPA file and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Member Center, I delete the ad-hoc distribution provisioning and create again.
After recompile, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an OTA build, you don't need an ad-hoc one.  Toss those profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I fixed it because I remembered I got a new phone, so I hooked it up with Xcode (developer mode) and added the device to the provisioning profile and re-installed the profile.